# Sed command failing because of / in replacement pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I have this ECS task definition as follow:

```
{
    ...
    "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:1.0",
    ...
    "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:latest",
    ....
}
```

I need to replace only the first "image" value, for instance:

```
{
    ...
    "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:2.0",
    ...
    "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:latest",
    ....
}
```

Here's my command `sed -e "s/.*foo:.*/\"image\":\"${REPO}:${VERSION}\",/" taskdef.json`

Where `REPO=123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo` and `VERSION=2.0`

This is the error I got:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 70: unknown option to `s'
```

This happens because the slash `/` from `REPO` variable.

Comment: Why not use a tool that's designed for the task, like `jq`?

Comment: Do you need to replace the first `image` value or the first text containing `foo`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any character as the delimiter for `s' commands in sed, the first character after `s` will be the delimiter. For example - `#`

```
sed -e "s#foo:.*#\"image\":\"${REPO}:${VERSION}\",#" taskdef.json
```

Will resolve this particular issue (assuming no `#` in `$REPO` or `$VERSION`) as the `/` will no longer break the pattern.

Comment: Good answer! I added a little bit of explanation to make it more verbose as to why/how it will solve OP's problem

Comment: Good answer? It's just shifted the problem character from `/` to `#` and it'll fail for various other characters (try it if REPO includes a `&` or `\1`) and it'll change every occurrence of the regexp, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the value for the first image would be:

```
$ awk -v repo="$REPO" -v vers="$VERSION" '
    !f && ($1~/"image"/) { f=1; sub(/:.*/,""); $0=$0 ": \"" repo ":" vers "\"," } 1
' file
{
    ...
    "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:2.0",
    ...
    "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:latest",
    ....
}
```

The above would convert escape sequences to their literal characters (e.g. `\t` to a literal tab character) if they appeared in REPO or VERSION. It's a trivial workaround if that's a possible issue (just set them on the command line or export them then access with ENVIRON[]) and it'll work no matter what other characters appear in the strings since it's using literal string functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The right way with json processor called ***jq*** (v1.5):

Sample *ECS* task definition `task.json`:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "wordpress",
      "links": [
        "mysql"
      ],
      "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:1.0",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memory": 500,
      "cpu": 10
    },
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        }
      ],
      "name": "mysql",
      "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:latest",
      "cpu": 10,
      "memory": 500,
      "essential": true
    }
  ],
  "family": "hello_world"
}
```

---

The job:

```
jq '.containerDefinitions[0].image = (.containerDefinitions[0].image | sub("1.0$";"2.0"))' task.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "wordpress",
      "links": [
        "mysql"
      ],
      "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:2.0",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memory": 500,
      "cpu": 10
    },
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        }
      ],
      "name": "mysql",
      "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:latest",
      "cpu": 10,
      "memory": 500,
      "essential": true
    }
  ],
  "family": "hello_world"
}
```